# Is there a word that is specific to a number being divisible specifically by 5?

Tags: mathematics, ordinal-numbers, germanic-vs-latinate-vocabulary

I'm searching for a word that would indicate an attraction to — or consistent use of — numbers that are divisible by "5".

Example:

> Tom always bets on numbers ending in 5 or 0 because he is a/an "_____________".

Comment: Not in English. _Even_ and _odd_ is it for divisibility classes. There ought to be one for 3, but there isn't. With numbers divisible by 5, "round numbers" is often used, at least for the even ones, but (say) 85 doesn't feel like a round number (though 75 does).

Comment: "idiot" would seem to fit the blank.

Comment: Thinking that a phone ending in 5 or 0 is easier to remember and businesslike is logical. Thinking that 5 and 0 are lucky for you is superstitious.

Comment: @JohnLawler “Quarterable” for divisible by four.

Comment: "Halveable" too (@JohnLawler) but it's a poor substitute for "even" if you want to specify that the result is an integer. I'm more surprised there's nothing for 10 given that we work in base 10.

Answer (score 1):

For something evenly divisible by five, I suggest **quinquesectable**, from **[quinquesect](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quinquesect)**.

Definition from Wiktionary:

> v.
> quinquesect
> (transitive, mathematics) To divide (a quantity, angle etc.) into five equal parts.

OED definition is "to cut into five (equal) parts" with a first reference from 1697.

Comment: Other than the "quin" Prefix already suggested in my Answer, I want to Point out that this will not fit the given sentence "Tom is .... quinquesectable" , unless the Intention is to chop Tom up !!

Comment: @Prem Yes, it does not fit the blank. I like the word “pentamerous” for that purpose, because it suggests “amorous”, but the accepted meaning does not fit easily unless Tom sees five equal parts to himself in some way.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no "Exact" Match, you might want to consider these "Close" Matches:

> **[Penta](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/penta-) ; [Pentatonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pentatonic&redirect=no)** : Involving 5 ; A Pentatonic scale
> **[Quinary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quinary) ; [Quincunx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quincunx)** : Consisting of five ; Arranged by fives

You could change your sentence structure to use those words:

> Tom always bets on numbers ending in 5 or 0 because he is "Pentatonic".
> Tom always bets on numbers ending in 5 or 0 because he is attracted to "Quinary" Items.
> Tom always bets on numbers ending in 5 or 0 because he is a "Penta[-Phile](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/-phile)".
> Tom always bets on numbers ending in 5 or 0 because he has a "Quincunx" Obsession.

These words (and Derived words) are **Closely** about 5, not **Exactly** about multiples of 5.

Comment: Non-standard, Prem!

Comment: These words are absolutely not main stream : "Penta-" is a common Prefix , used here with a common Suffix "-Phile" ! "Quinary" & "Quincunx" are niche ! @EdwinAshworth ; I will add few references !

Comment: "Pentatonic" is the most objectionable to me out of these, because it has a very specific (and not uncommon) meaning in music, which doesn't apply to people.

Comment: I know what you mean , @MarcInManhattan , but the musical term is "Pentatonic **Scale**" , where the word "Scale" makes it a musical term ; "Pentatonic" is Adjectival , which might be usable in non-musical areas too ! It will still be non-standard !

Comment: @Prem, "pentatonic" is music-specific even without "scale". The "tonic" indicates musical pitches. "Quincunx" doesn't mean a number divisible by 5, it means the arrangement of five objects at the corners and centre of a square, as on the "5" side of a die. But there's a linguistic reason not to use the words you suggest: if you use them, people won't understand your intended meaning from your words.

Comment: Based on all the comments , I think this answer should be removed ! I will do that removal in a couple of hours , allowing all comments to be read ; @RosieF